# What is difference between feature to raster, feature to polygon and polygon to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I saw in ArcMap under Conversion tools, feature to polygon, feature to raster, polygon to raster.

Does feature mean vector?

Answer (score 0):

The three simple feature types of points, lines and polygons are all vector data types.

The functionality provided by each of the conversion tools you mention is described on their Online Help pages. I would assume that a tool converting from features can be used with input point, line or polygon feature classes.